# Wondering about the Windows 7 serial number my laptop has, and its uses

Tags: laptop, windows-7-backup

So that's the serial number of my pre-installed windows copy, I take it. But am I allowed to use it again when, say, I don't know, my system gets crippled by a sneaky virus?

If I format my computer and install windows starter again from a USB drive (speculating. I've never format before, I suppose is completely possible) Is that serial number still valid?

I'm talking about the number printed on the back of my laptop.

I have an Acer Aspire One model D255.

Comment: Edit your post to include the Make and Model of the notebook.

Comment: @Moab, not necessary. The same Windows licensing rules apply across the board.

Comment: @ nhinkle, I asked for another reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that license will still be valid for use on the laptop it was sold on in the case of a clean install.

Comment: That is so sweet. But, I don't have my windows copy anywhere, it didn't came with a disk. Is there a place where I can download it legally?

Comment: Your laptop manufacturer may have installed some software that lets you create a set of 'recovery discs'.

Comment: Not really, no. Certainly there isn't anywhere that it is offered by Microsoft. If your laptop didn't come with a disk, it is likely that there is a "restore partition" that you can access by choosing the boot device in the BIOS which will allow you reinstall/repair the OS.

Comment: It should be clarified that those OEM keys WILL NOT WORK WITH RETAIL COPIES OF WINDOWS.  You cannot just grab a copy off the shelf and expect it to work; you need to follow @Linker3000's advice and make the manufacturer recovery disks.  (Note that those are normally BIOS key'd and won't even require you to enter the license key.)

Comment: @Shinrai - is that something new with Windows 7? It hasn't given me trouble before with XP and Vista.

Comment: @TZHX - It's not new, but I think there were certain combinations of OEMs and OS versions that it may have worked for - it can vary a lot.  You might get lucky and get it to work with a retail copy but I wouldn't hold my breath.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use it to reinstall Windows again on that laptop if you need to.

One tip though - keep a note of the licence code somewhere safe (or take a picture of it) because I have seen many laptops (like mine!) where the licence sticker has become so damaged/scuffed by the way the laptop is used/handled that the key is unreadable.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. Thanks a bunch! Point for you, also.

Comment: +1 for "Take a picture of the license key".  When we ship PCs, we ship a photocopy of it for just that reason.